# NSArray of NSStrings is returning just one big string in one object, and I need a lot of objects

Tags: ios, json, nsstring, nsmutablearray, substring

I have a NSArray that get in WS by JSON some date values.
That is what my NSLOG are returning:
    "2013-05-31T17:00:00Z",
    "2013-05-31T17:30:00Z",
    "2013-05-31T18:00:00Z",
    "2013-05-31T20:00:00Z",
...

I need a new NSArray returning just the hour and minute, like that:
"17:00",
"17:30",
"18:00",
"20:00",
...

I was doing something like:

```
        for (int a =0; a<array2.count; a++)
        {
            NSString *myString = [array2 objectAtIndex:a];
            NSString *horaDeInicio = [myString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(11, 5)];
            [horariosProgramas addObject:horaDeInicio];
        }
```

And the response is what I need, but  the response came in only ONE BIG STRING. So my array have just one object. I need separate this big string in objects. How can I do this??
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us how you create and then display or use `horariosProgramas` so as to conclude that it's become one big string?

Comment: in viewDidLoad:
horariosProgramas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

and When I select a button in a row in tableview
detailEmissoraViewController.horariosProgramas = [horariosProgramas objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];

and detailEmissoraViewController, horariosPrograma is a property.
In cellForRowAtIndexPath I try to use
NSString *subCellValue = [horariosProgramas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = subCellValue;

But it's crash

-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: But if you've done `.horariosProgramas = [horariosProgramas objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];` then surely the local property is a string, not an array, causing the problem when you next try `subCellValue = [horariosProgramas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`?

Comment: hum, yes you are right! So how can I fix this??

Answer (score 3):

Just separate it by the T and Z characters. Do something like this:

```
for (int a =0; a<array2.count; a++)
{
     NSString *myString = [array2 objectAtIndex:a];
     NSArray *arr = [myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"TZ"]];
     NSString *yourDate = [arr objectAtIndex:1];

     [horariosProgramas addObject:yourDate];
}
```

Confirm your array indexes with print statements and you'll be on your way.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the dates using dateFormatter would be better in a long run and you want to change the display format or something

```
NSArray *array2= @[@"2013-05-31T17:00:00Z", 
                   @"2013-05-31T17:30:00Z", 
                   @"2013-05-31T18:00:00Z", 
                   @"2013-05-31T20:00:00Z"];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];

NSString *inputDateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
NSString *outputDateFormat = @"HH:mm";

for (NSString *dateString in array2) {
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:inputDateFormat];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:outputDateFormat];
    [horariosProgramas addObject:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];
}
```